# Conditional breakpoint on register containing string catch everything

Tags: x64dbg, breakpoint, register

I am trying to setup a conditional breakpoint to catch a specific string ("Sessions") that will be on `ESI` register but it catches everything:

[image]

I also tried with dereferenced register `[ESI] == "Sessions"` but it didn't work.
What is the problem with my conditional breakpoint?

Comment: As far as I know, at least some time ago, x64dbg didn't handle string comparison. [here](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/2067) and [here](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/1485) are github issues discussing your problem. Possibly you can bypass it by installing some plugins, but this solution is far from perfect.

Comment: This is still a feature that’s not implemented. Someone started working on it by extending expression functions, but it’s still WIP.

Comment: strstr(utf16(esi),"Sessions") ?